# How to solve infix expression for calculator app

Tags: java, android, algorithm, data-structures, calculator

I am creating calculator application which takes infix expression as input and on click of '=' button app will solve expression and give result or error in case of invalid expression.

So far I have managed to convert infix to post fix using stack and solve expression but its limitation is it takes only one number as operand.

Example:

> 1+2(3*3)-4^2  //working
>
> 11+2(13*3)-4^20  //not working
>
> 1.2+2.4(10.5*.5)-4^2 //not working

input is the string expression and while calculation we have to follow BODMAS rule and operators of equal precedence must be evaluated from left to right.

Can any one provide me insight into how to solve this problem? What algorithms should I use? What will be the most efficient way to handle different edge cases? Link to a working example.

Comment: Check the Reverse Polish Notation

Comment: The standard solution is the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). You'll need to modify that a bit to handle numbers with more than a single digit, though. In fact, that looks like your problem right now. You can handle `1+(3*3)-4^2`, but you fail when the numbers have multiple characters. So it sound like your issue is lexical parsing. But it's hard to tell because you didn't post any code and didn't give any description other than "not working".

Answer (score 0):

I included a space after the number, while converting I was waiting for a space to determine whether the number is complete or not. By this way I was able to solve that. 
[You can check this code if you want.](https://github.com/Pronoy999/Calculator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/pronoymukherjee/calculator_beta1/MainActivity.java)